# How Can I Create a PDF Quotation File from Winform?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, winforms

[alt text http://img517.imageshack.us/img517/8124/56267347.jpg](http://img517.imageshack.us/img517/8124/56267347.jpg)

Assuming i have a winform that has a button called "Create a Quote". Once user clicks it,
a PDF File gets created on desktop. The PDF File has a fixed design/structure e.g. the logo is at the top left corner, the headers are fixed, etc. However, the data it self is pulled from a database.

As you see above, Quotation #, Description, Qty, U.P (USD), T.P (USD) records should be fetched from the db and dumped in the pdf template then create the pdf for user.

I haven't done this before. I hope my question is clear enough. Feel free to put useful web links that help me achieve it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look at two of the most popular open-source PDF libraries for C#, namely:

[ITextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) and [PDFSharp](http://www.pdfsharp.net/)

Both allow you to programatically create PDF files. Here's a quick 'hello word' example with PDFSharp:

```
  // Create a new PDF document
  PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
  document.Info.Title = "Created with PDFsharp";

  // Create an empty page
  PdfPage page = document.AddPage();

  // Get an XGraphics object for drawing
  XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);

  // Create a font
  XFont font = new XFont("Verdana", 20, XFontStyle.BoldItalic);

  // Draw the text
  gfx.DrawString("Hello, World!", font, XBrushes.Black,
    new XRect(0, 0, page.Width, page.Height),
    XStringFormats.Center);

  // Save the document...
  const string filename = "HelloWorld.pdf";
  document.Save(filename);
  // ...and start a viewer.
  Process.Start(filename);
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. But what if I do not want to save the document, but instead just open the PDF file in viewer and let the user decide whether to save or not.

Comment: In ASP.NET you can just output the generated PDF to the response stream. If the user has a viewer installed then it will automatically open in that. See http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/Clock-sample.ashx for an example.